# Oracle SQL show result of specific combination of two column values in each row

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to ask for help with following issue. I have table which is generated randomly each time. In that table, I would like to display information, if there is more than 0 occurences of combination of group and type.

For example this is randomly generated table:

| GROUP | TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| A | T |
| A | T |
| C | P |
| B | T |
| A | P |
| C | P |

And I would like to see, if there is more than 0 occurences of each group with type T.

So in this case group "A" has more than 0 occurences of type "T", so each row will display "1" for group A. Same for group "B" and group "C" has no occurences of type "T", so each row of C will show 0 in additional column. Like following result:

| GROUP | TYPE | RES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | T | 1 |
| A | T | 1 |
| C | P | 0 |
| B | T | 1 |
| A | P | 1 |
| C | P | 0 |

Is there pls query, which could solve this?

Thank you in advance,

Brgds

Comment: @forpas There is a row for that `group` with a `type` of `T`.

Comment: @MT0 I guess I read *more than 0* as *more than 1*!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation in an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       LEAST(
         COUNT(CASE type WHEN 'T' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY "GROUP"),
         1
       ) AS res
FROM   table_name t
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( "GROUP", TYPE ) AS
SELECT 'A', 'T' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'T' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'P' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'T' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'P' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'P' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | GROUP | TYPE | RES |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | A | P | 1 |
> | A | T | 1 |
> | A | T | 1 |
> | B | T | 1 |
> | C | P | 0 |
> | C | P | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c55d6745fd891210a38ec5dc8616e484)*

Comment: Perfect, working great. Thank you very much

Comment: Hm, LEAST. Smart! I'd go for another CASE.

Comment: `CASE COUNT(CASE type WHEN 'T' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY "GROUP") WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END` would also work (but its more to type).

Comment: I know. That's why I prefer your LEAST over my double CASE idea.